# _dependents.isEmpty: is not true. (when StackNavigation used from Drawer Navigation)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**I Have searched all the possible ways but failed that's why i am posting it here please help:**

I am working on app using redux. But i am facing some issues. My App has the following:

1. Stack Navigation in starting. Login and Registration page.
2. After Successful login drawer Navigation will open.
3. Inside drawer there is listVIew and when i click on any row of list view detail page will open that's stack Navigator. the application works fine till this step.
   but when i do step 4
4. Going back from detail page (stack Navigator) to list view of Drawer Navigation i faced this issue.

> ════════ (2) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4701 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true.
>   The relevant error-causing widget was: 
>     MaterialApp file:///home/anju/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_training_app/lib/main.dart:37:16
>   ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ (3) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1786 pos 12: '_elements.contains(element)': is not true.
>   The relevant error-causing widget was: 
>     MaterialApp file:///home/anju/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_training_app/lib/main.dart:37:16
>   ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ (4) Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 2430 pos 16: '!_dirtyElements[index]._active || _dirtyElements[index]._debugIsInScope(context)': is not true.
>   ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Below given is my flutter Doctor output.

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
>
> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Linux, locale en_IN)
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.42.0)
>
> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
>
> • No issues found!

My main.dart file contains:

```
runApp(StoreProvider(
        store: store,
        child: MaterialApp(
            initialRoute: '/login',
            routes: {
                '/login': (context) => Login(),
                '/registration': (context) => Registration(),
                '/dashboard': (context) => MainMenu()
            }
        )));
```

My List View Code to navigate to detail page:

```
           ListTile(
                       leading: Container(
                           padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                           child: Icon( Icons.insert_comment )
                       ),
                       title: Text(post.title),
                       subtitle: Text(post.body),
                       trailing: Container(
                           padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                           child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right)
                       ),
                       onTap: () {
                           Navigator.of(context).push(
                               MaterialPageRoute(
                                   builder: (context) {
                                       return PostDetail();
                                   },
                               ),
                           );
                       }
```

From Detail page navigation is used like this:

```
onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) {
                                      return Posts();
                                  },
                              ),
                    );
    }
```

**NOTE: If you want i can share the link of code i had put on GITHUB.**

Comment: You are not navigating back from the `PostDetail` route, you are instead navigating to a new `Posts` route. Also, please show the first error you are getting and its stack trace. You've only shown errors 2, 3 and 4 which are not relevant

Comment: i have used "Navigator.of(context).pop()" and it works thank you @Ovidiu

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the errors provided isn't really helpful on this issue. The error was caused because you're trying to get back from `PostDetail` to `Posts` by creating a new one. If `Posts` is on the Navigation stack, `Navigator.of(context).pop()` should help you get back to the previous screen.